# Is there a way I can cache a LINQ parameter and reuse it later?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way I can cache a LINQ parameter and reuse it later for optimization?

Here is my situation.

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    ProjectCollection GetProjects();
    // ...
}

public class ProjectCollection
{
    List<Project> EmployeeProjects { get; private set; }
    // ...
}

public class Project
{
    public Guid ProjectId { get; private set; }
    // ...
}
```

Now given a list of employees List, and a given ProjectId (guid), I need to retrieve the Project object.

I've tried a combination of two LINQ statements, one to find the right employee, and one to find the right project. **But is there a way to do it in one statement, or at least optimize it by caching the employee somewhere?**

```
public Project GetProject(List<IEmployee> employees, Guid id)
{
    Project rtn = null;

    // Step 1: Retrieve the employee who has the right project.
    var employeeWithProject = employees.Where (e => e.GetProjects().EmployeeProjects.Any(p => p.ProjectId.Equals(guid))).FirstOrDefault(); // Note: This retrieves the employee. But I need to cache the part [e.GetProjects().EmployeeProjects] to query it later.

    if employeeWithProject != null)
    {
        // Step 2: Retrieve the project itself.
        rtn = employeeWithProject.GetProjects().EmployeeProjects.Where(p => p.ProjectId.Equals(guid)).FirstOrDefault(); // Note: This retrieves the actual project from the previously set employeeWithProject
    }

    return rtn; // nothing found
}
```

I really don't like this solution, and was wondering if anyone could help me optimize it. It basically iterates through the Projectcollection twice. So if anyone can think of a way to do the whole thing with a single LINQ statement I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
var employeeWithProject = employees
   .Select(e => e.GetProjects().EmployeeProjects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectId.Equals(guid)))
   .FirstOrDefault(x=> x != null);
```

here you're selecting the wanted projects from the employees, and then getting the first one that isn't null

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`SelectMany` could work here too.

```
static public Project GetProject(List<Employee> employees, Guid id)
   => employees
     .SelectMany( e => e.GetProjects()?.EmployeeProjects)
     .FirstOrDefault( p => p.ProjectId == id);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. Seeing and studying different ways of solving the same problem is very beneficial.